# Combining .blend files

Tags: modeling

I'm new to Blender and recently downloaded several free pre-rigged models to practice with. However, they are all separate files (being created by multiple authors). What is the most painless method of importing them into a master .blend file?

Comment: Open up a second instance of blender (just double click the icon again), delete the default cube, camera and light, then copy (Ctrl+C) the object from it's own file and paste (Ctrl+V ) into the empty blender project. Copy the models from each different file into the "master" (formerly empty) one. You can add each new object to it's own collection if you want/need to.

Comment: You can also use the File > Append function